# jQuery: Forcing to fadeOut() first and then prepend() div

Tags: jquery

On this page, when you click on text, div1 must fade out and delete itself and div2 must appear. The thing is script prepends div2 first and then div1 fades out. How can I force script to make div1 fade out and then prepend div2?

NOTES:

1. This is the simplest case of my problem. Don't suggest me to just change text or something alternative since in my webpage that I'm trying to implement, interchanging div's is inevitable (div's have a lot of data).
2. I must use prepend(), so no append() or appendTo() suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
        <script src = "script.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "div1">
            <h1 id = "text1">This is div1</h1>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $(document).on ("click", "#text1", function() {

        $("#div1").fadeOut (function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
        $("#div2")
            .hide()
            .append ("<h1 id = 'text2'>This is div2</div>")
            .fadeIn();
    });

    $(document).on ("click", "#text2", function() {

        $("#div2").fadeOut (function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
        $("#div1")
            .hide()
            .append ("<h1 id = 'text1'>This is div1</div>")
            .fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the `fadeIn` after the `remove` in `fadeout`'s callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tYM9G/5/)

```
$(document).on ("click", "#text1", function() {

    $("#div1").fadeOut (function() {

        $(this).remove();

        $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
        $("#div2")
        .hide()
        .append ("<h1 id = 'text2'>This is div2</div>")
        .fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just move fadeIn into the callback. Check here: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/WGsGu/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("click", "#text1", function () {

        $("#div1").fadeOut(function () {

            $(this).remove();
            $("body").prepend("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
            $("#div2")
                .hide()
                .append("<h1 id = 'text2'>This is div2</div>")
                .fadeIn();

        });
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#text2", function () {

        $("#div2").fadeOut(function () {

            $(this).remove();
            $("body").prepend("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
            $("#div1")
                .hide()
                .append("<h1 id = 'text1'>This is div1</div>")
                .fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.promise()` and `.done()`:

```
    $(document).on ("click", "#text1", function() {

       $("#div1").fadeOut (function() {
          $(this).remove();
       }).promise().done(function(){ // <----here
          $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
          $("#div2")
             .hide()
             .append ("<h1 id = 'text2'>This is div2</div>")
             .fadeIn();
       });        
    });

    $(document).on ("click", "#text2", function() {
       $("#div2").fadeOut (function() {
          $(this).remove();
       }).promise().done(function(){ // <----here
          $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
          $("#div1")
             .hide()
             .append ("<h1 id = 'text1'>This is div1</div>")
             .fadeIn();
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You want like this? http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/tcJF9/

Just use `.delay(800)` to .fadeIn('div').

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $(document).on ("click", "#text1", function() {

        $("#div1").fadeOut (function() {

            $(this).remove();

        });
        $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div2'></div>");
        $("#div2")
            .hide()
            .append ("<h1 id = 'text2'>This is div2</div>")
            .delay(800).fadeIn();
    });

    $(document).on ("click", "#text2", function() {

        $("#div2").fadeOut (function() {

            $(this).remove();

        });
        $("body").prepend ("<div id = 'div1'></div>");
        $("#div1")
            .hide()
            .append ("<h1 id = 'text1'>This is div1</div>")
            .delay(800).fadeIn();
    });
});
```